# css/html height 100% not working jQuery + Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-studio

I just installed phonegap on Android Studios and everything was working fine, but then I installed jQuery Mobile and jQuery and all of my height: 100%; stopped matching  their parents.

Example:

html: `<body><div id='deviceready'></div></body>`

css: `html, body { height: 100%; } #deviceready { height: 100%; }`

If I alert `$("#deviceready").css("height")` or `$("#deviceready").height()`
I get `434`

If I alert `$("body").height()` or `$("body").css("height")` I get `693`

If I then use `$("#deviceready").css("height", $("body").height() + "px")`, `$("#deviceready").css("height", $("body").css("height"))` or `$("#deviceready").height($("body").height())` Nothing happens... I can't get #deviceready to match the height of the parent...

Comment: jquery mobile comes with it's own css, so it's messing with your height 100%, so, don't use jquery mobile

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for the response, I removed jquery mobile and nothing changed at first, but the $("#deviceready").height($(window).height()); started working, so I placed that in my receivedEvent: function